# Can a reaction with positive Gibbs free energy change ever occur?

Tags: energy, enthalpy, entropy, free-energy

If you have an endothermic reaction with a negative entropy change, is it still possible to induce the reaction in some way despite the fact that the Gibbs free energy change is positive or all temperatures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, $\Delta G = -RT\ln K$.

If a reaction is endothermic with a negative entropy change, $\Delta G$ is positive.

That $\Delta G$ is positive only means that $K<1$.

$\Delta G$ would need to approach infinity for $K$ to approach zero.

Therefore, at equilibrium, there will always be some products in principle no matter how unfavorable the reaction.

As a practical matter, the reaction would need to be only slightly endothermic and having only a slight negative entropy change to get a significant amount of product.

However, if the small amount of product is continuously removed from the system, as for example by precipitation from a liquid phase, or gas bubbling out of a liquid phase, or by liquid-liquid extraction, one can keep the reaction going forward.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Is K the equilibrium constant in this equation? I have not come across this equation before...

Comment: The equation is actually the definition of standard equilibrium constant, so it is a very important equation: http://goldbook.iupac.org/S05915.html

Comment: Why does the ozone layer exist although the Gibbs energy for its formation is positive?

Comment: @Shub diatomic oxygen in dissociated in to monoatomic oxygen by ultraviolet light, then the monoatomic oxygen reacts with diatomic oxygen to form ozone:  https://csl.noaa.gov/assessments/ozone/2010/twentyquestions/Q2.pdf